# CSS3 border radius issue when position/dimensions not a whole width

Tags: javascript, css

Noticed an issue with rounded corners in CSS3 when a position and/or dimensions are not a whole number. Not sure if it's browser or CSS related.

Currently attaching a label to icons on Google Maps. Sometimes a position makes a very slight change, causing the position of the attached label (a div with CSS3 border radius) to render improperly. Have a look:

[image: 6 and 7 are div labels attached to GMaps markers]

Notice how 6 is missing the bottom row of pixels which has been added visually to the top of the div. But 7 is normal and whole.

Code relevant to attaching each label:

```
// Implement draw
Label.prototype.draw = function() {
     var projection = this.getProjection();
     var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));
     var div = this.div_;
     div.style.left = position.x + 'px';
     div.style.top = position.y + 'px';
     div.style.display = this.get('display');
     div.style.zIndex = this.get('zIndex'); //ALLOW LABEL TO OVERLAY MARKER
     this.span_.innerHTML = this.get('text').toString();
};
```

**Any thoughts or fixes? Is the problem Javascript, GMaps, browser, or CSS? Thanks!**

Comment: Use whole numbers when positioning with pixels.

Comment: that did just the trick! Add it as an answer so I can accept it ;) FYI code was Math.round(position.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whole numbers when positioning with pixels as they are an absolute measurement.

Comment: Perfect! Rounding the positions on the fly solved it. Math.round(position.x)